# Does a NetApp NAS provide features with VMware compared to a ZFS based NAS?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, zfs, netapp

Are there feature advantages from a VMware point of view to use a NetApp nas instead of a ZFS based NAS running e.g. OmniOS?

Another way to formulate the question: Are there features unlocked when using a NetApp NAS compared to a ZFS based NAS? E.G. provisioning or perhaps performance because VMware can send commands to the NetApp.

My setup would be as simple as possible. No clustering or HA, just one disk array in each case.

Comment: I think this question is OT the way it's currently written, because I'm not sure there can be an answer that isn't primarily opinion.  But you may get some concrete experience-based comment on using a NetApp as backing store for VMWare on the unofficial NetApp admins mailing list, at http://www.teaparty.net/mailman/listinfo/toasters (disclaimer: I run the list).

Comment: Hopefully it should be a yes/no kind of answer with the features you get unlocked if the answer is yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [VMware compatibility guide includes a comprehensive storage section](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?deviceCategory=san) that lists the supported storage solutions and provides details on what features are available for each listing. You can also filter the search results by the features.

After locating a listing you can drill-down into it to see the details. You should be looking for arrays that support relevant features from [VAAI](http://www.vmware.com/resources/techresources/10337) the VMware vSphere Storage APIs for Array Integration. VAAI are features supported by some arrays that allow VMware to offload specific operations onto the storage device itself. This can help make operations such as cloning and snapshots much faster. The individual listing will provide details on whether VAAI is supported by an array and which features are supported.

While I am not familiar with the OmnioOs, I believe Oracle and others have ZFS based storage arrays that are supported with VMware.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

> vStorage APIs for Array Integration

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1021976

Check the HCL for Storage. OmniOS isn't a listed partner. NetApp is.

Comment: But there are other options ([here](http://www.osnexus.com/storage-appliance-os/), [here](http://www.nexenta.com/products/nexentastor) and [here](http://www.dnuk.com/zetavault/features/)) for supported ZFS-based NAS. So NetApp isn't a necessity.

Comment: Sure - I was responding to the example. I'm sure she can look up other vendors in the HCL.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mfinni said, check VMware's Hardware Compatability List for a comprehensive list of supported storage devices.

The NetApp offers several features that are not available on a generic ZFS-based NAS, particularly with Backups, storage provisioning and the 50% Virtualization guarantee.

http://www.netapp.com/us/solutions/virtualization/server/server-vmware.aspx

However, some ZFS appliances vendors also try to engineer their product to work better with VMware. ome appliances have achieved higher levels of integration then others. For example, see the TrueNAS device from iXsystems. iXsystems is the main developer of FreeNAS.

- http://www.ixsystems.com/whats-new/ixsystems-incs-truenas-achieves-vmware-ready-status/
- https://solutionexchange.vmware.com/store/products/truenas